# ask-cli api or lambda does not exist

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, ask-cli

I am wondering why ask-cli does not work if I want to list the commands. Does anybody know the reason? I could run ask deploy and can see my skill up and running on developer.amazon.com

```
> ask -v
1.1.2
> ask --help
  Usage: ask [options] [command]

  Command Line Interface for Alexa Skill Management API

  Commands:

    init [options]      initialize the ask-cli with your Amazon developer account credentials
    deploy [options]    deploy a skill to your developer account
    new [options]       create a new skill project on your computer
    clone [options]     clone an existing skill project on your computer
    simulate [options]  simulate a user using your skill
    lambda              list of AWS Lambda commands
    api                 list of Alexa Skill Management API commands
    help [cmd]          display help for [cmd]

> ask lambda

  ask-lambda(1) does not exist, try --help

> ask api

  ask-api(1) does not exist, try --help
```

Answer (score 1):

After an installation of ask-cli via npm everything works as expected:

```
> npm install -g ask-cli
```

I used before brew to install ask-cli.